# using static class methods in another class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, subclass

I want to use certain static methods from another class in my code, but getting a weird error.

```
class Mouth {
  static greet() {
    console.log('Mouth.greet')
  }
}

class DogMouth extends Mouth {
  static greet() {
    console.log('DogMouth.woof')
  }
}

class Animal {
  mouth: Mouth
  constructor() {
    this.mouth = Mouth
  }

  greet() {
    this.mouth.greet()  // fails with Property 'greet' is a static member of type 'Mouth'
    Mouth.greet() // this works but should be the same thing?
    console.log('Animal.greet')
  }

}

class Dog extends Animal {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.mouth = DogMouth
  }
}

function main() {
  const pup = new Dog()
  pup.greet()
}

main()
```

I created a typescript [playground example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2BXALgC2gbwFDWhZYyAlsNAOYBOAplcgBQCUmOu0w8AdhPCFQHQh4ZOgHIEKVH0o1kIhiwC%20WJVlCQYAESHi00KgA9kVDgBMYO9Nlz5CJctVqNmrNp268BQ0VrIW%20Ad3h4ADM5RWUsVXAoaABBDiIAWzAQZ2hEpDQALjhM1BZ2LmQKRGBkeAonK1Y0Igg%20DIloAF5ciXDcaUcmatxa%20sa0KQd6eRc-LtGWXEL3fkFhEXiklOGZMNwlFTUYnz1DYzM4hOTU7AK3YtLyyp7pvEQABypb%20-6GvJboHwtwlWDEBwykROOkwEQOFULkVoI8nl8OFR-N8vGNYU81t0IlhkhDGFggA)

So these are the problem lines, where `this.mouth` is defined to be the class `Mouth`
collapsing the constructor etc code its the same as this:

```
    this.mouth = Mouth
    this.mouth.greet()  // fails with Property 'greet' is a static member of type 'Mouth'
    Mouth.greet() // this works but should be the same thing?
```

If this is confusing I'm wondering what better patterns I could use where I need certain methods to do different things based on the subclass. But ideally those methods are also available as static methods *outside* the subclass.

Comment: `Mouth` is the type of the instances. The class itself is `typeof Mouth`. i.e. you need to say:  `mouth: typeof Mouth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your property to be an instance of `Mouth`

```
mouth: Mouth
```

... but static methods are not available on instances

> Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

So the soultion is, to set the correct type or let TS do it for you:

```
class Animal {
  // TS will detect type from assignment
  mouth = Mouth;

  // Set type manually and assign
  // mouth: typeof Mouth = Mouth;

  // Set type only (and assign later)
  // mouth: typeof Mouth;

  // NOT WHAT YOU WANT (instance, static methods not available)
  // mouth: Mouth = new Mouth();

  greet() {
    this.mouth.greet()
    Mouth.greet()
    console.log('Animal.greet')
  }
}
```

Comment: got it thanks! `mouth: Mouth` is a setup for an instance of Mouth, not the Mouth class itself. `mouth = Mouth` does the assignment and lets TS handle the types.

Comment: I've added some more comments to make it more obvious in code.